# How to store selected Ringtone in android studio?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
public void onRingtone(View view) {
        final Uri currentTone= RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Setting.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Ringtone");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentTone);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
    }
```

I have this onClick method to select available Ringtone from it's own device.
When startActivityForResult() method is called it redirect to custom popup dialog from where user can select Ringtone and at same time it starts that Ringtone. 
That's Ok.
But I want to save that Ringtone to play it on another activity.
So what should I do?
Can I store it in database(SQLite), or in SharedPreference or any other way?

**Edit:**
I don't know why my question get closed even if I provided all information.But still giving more information, to understand my question better.

Xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Ringtone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/sp2"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="onRingtone"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp">
```

The above method is called when user selects the Ringtone. I got one answer which told me to use SharedPreference to store uri.
But uri is declared final on the first line of method. And even it doesn't stores selected ringtone. On startActivityForResult() method takes the selected ringtone. So I think work need to be done with this method return or on the intent object.

If I create object of SharedPreference in this java file how can I get access to other acivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to retrieve `Uri` corresponding to the picked tone in onActivityResult().

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 999) {
        Uri ringtoneUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    }
}
```

You can then store it in the current activity as a member and pass it through an intent to another activity